# PHP permanent cookie

Tags: php, cookies

How do I set up a cookie that won't never expire, even when the user closes his browser or stops his machine?

Thanks!

Comment: This is pretty clearly explained right on the [`setcookie`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) docs page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to have a 'permanent' cookie, but rather one that expires very very far into the future. Just because you remained logged into a website/service the next time you return or after you close your browser, does not mean that there is no expiration date on the cookie.

Check out the [PHP documentation on setting the lifetime of a cookie](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

Comment: In facebook for example you stay logged even when you shut down your machine or you close the browser. The cookie is there until you click on logout. How do I make the very same thing?

Comment: See my update - just because you remain logged into Facebook doesn't mean they have a 'permanent' cookie. I can't speak to its exact design and implementation, but it is very likely set to expire at a date very far into the future.

Comment: @DiegoP:  There are a bunch of Facebook cookies.  Some expire when I close the window, one expires next week, a few expire next month, and a couple expire in two years, but **no** FB cookie will last forever.

Comment: If you have a reason to be nasty, you could use [evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/) for an extremely durable cookie.

Answer (score 2):

`setcookie("example", $cookievalue, time()+60*60*24*6004, "/", ".example.com");`

Impossible to set a cookie forever, browsers wouldn't allow that. (ps. it's amazing what wonders google will conjure up if you were to literally google the title of this question)

Comment: Bound to fail for 32bit systems using 32bit time_t's. It's not presently safe to set a date beyond early 2038 at present. Still far away, but don't count on the user having a 64bit system that does support years >2038.

Comment: so what happens? the entire cookie setting fails?

Comment: depends on the underlying system and how they process dates. could be an integer overflow, could get truncated and end up with a much "earlier" date than expected, etc...

Comment: By the time @MarcB's concern becomes a problem (on 2021-08-12), by the current looks it seems everyone would've migrated to a 64 bit system.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a expiration date which is very far from now:

```
setcookie("testCookie","value",mktime (0, 0, 0, 12, 31, 2015));
//Expires on 31 december 2015
```

Comment: 2015 is about as far away as 2000 was for all those "let's only use 2 digits for years" people...

Comment: At first I thought, "but this is only 21 days in the future?"  And then I looked at the date the answer was posted.  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
setcookie("cname" ,$value, mktime (0, 0, 0, 12, 31, 2015));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The user will always have the option to remove or block cookies. But you can always  set the expire date in the far future.